# Inheritance or nesting with docker compose

Tags: docker-compose

The best way to start our application is by using a docker compose we provide. The *docker-compose* starts all the services with the right configuration.

Now we would like to provide a *docker-compose* where the application runs with a different backend. In this compose 8 out 10 services are the same and 2 are different.

**How to achieve this without code duplication?**
I see that a service can extend a service from another docker-compose file, however this would still require to list all the 10 services in both files.

Answer (score 34):

With docker-compose 1.6 this should be possible.

Create a `docker-compose.yml` with your common services:

```
service01:
  image: image01
  links:
    - service02

service02:
  image: image02
```

And a second file, `docker-compose.prod.yml` with your unique services:

```
service03:
  image: image03
  links:
    - service02
```

Now you can start service 01, 02 and 03 with this command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml
```

For more information, see the official documentation:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files

Answer (score 31):

The easiest way to achieve this is to create a second compose file. In the second file, you can use the `extend` feature of Docker Compose which allows you to "inherit" services from another file: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/

Assuming your original file is `docker-compose.yaml`, you could create a `swap-backend-compose.yaml`:

```
service-one:
  extends:
    file: docker-compose.yaml
    service: service-one

service-two:
  extends:
    file: docker-compose.yaml
    service: service-two
  environment:
    - BACKEND=some_other_value
```

...and so on.

Answer (score 13):

As noted in the comments, [Version 3 deprecates the `extends` keyword](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-3), so here's a minimal example without it:

```yaml
# BASE - docker-compose.base.yml
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    build: .

# DEV - docker-compose.dev.yml
services:
  api:
    command: npm run dev

# PROD - docker-compose.prod.yml
services:
  api:
    command: npm run prod
```

A few notes:

- per-environment files (`.dev.yml`, `.prod.yml`) can inherit, add to and replace config options from the base file (`.base.yml`)
- in this example, the per-env files 1) inherit the `build` option 2) add their own `command` option
- the base file is typically named `docker-compose.yml`; I've added `.base` here just to highlight the inheritance aspect and because I favor more explicit names; keep in mind [docker-compose looks for `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` by default](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#understanding-multiple-compose-files).

Comment: And you would start your prod version like this: `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up`

Comment: Is there a way to remove a service with this technique? For instance, remove your api service in dev but keep it in prod.

Comment: Good question! If you find an answer, might be worth posting as a standalone Q&A.